# How to add 'Google Consent 'to flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, admob

In my application I use native ads from:
`firebase_admob, native_admob_controller, flutter_native_admob`.

```
child: NativeAdmob(
              // Your ad unit id
              adUnitID: adsAndroidID,
              controller: _nativeAdController,
              // Don't show loading widget when in loading state
            ),
```

How can I now add to it the information described under this link https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/android/quick-start ?

I trying run with https://pub.dev/packages/gdpr_dialog but this is only in english language.

Comment: Check [this](https://pub.dev/packages/admob_consent) plugin

Comment: @Rajen Raiyarela I tried, but copying the sample code from this page I still don't manage to call the dialog.

Additionally, I don't see the option to personalize the language so the message is in Polish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Main

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  admob_consent: '1.0.0' #if you will change the text
  admob_consent: ^1.0.0+1 #if you will use main
```

### initialization

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:admob_consent/admob_consent.dart';

final AdmobConsent _admobConsent = AdmobConsent();

_admobConsent.show(publisherId: "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_PUBLISHER_ID", privacyURL: "URL_TO_YOUR_PRIVACY_POLICY");
```

### Listener

You can listen to the `onConsentFormLoaded`, `onConsentFormOpened`, `onConsentFormClosed` and `onConsentFormError` streams.

```
_admobConsent.onConsentFormClosed.listen((bool status) {
    // Status true if personalized
    // Handle it, ie. set targetingInfo
});
```

## To use in Polish

When you want to use the plugin in polish, without creating a Google Founding Choices account, you need to use **this version of the [Plugin](https://github.com/Gimu/admob_consent/tree/574688e189e0ab45e556bae7903d0faf902383bf)**

**Version: '1.0.0'** (not the newest)

README.md from this commit [here](https://github.com/Gimu/admob_consent/blob/574688e189e0ab45e556bae7903d0faf902383bf/README.md)

Here you can edit the language files
(External Libraries/Flutter Plugins/admob_consent-1.0.0/android/src.main/assets)

[image]

There are a couple html files, these represent the consent query. You can either copy and revise one of these, but then you have to make sure that you also integrate them.

Therefore, if the target group is only Polish, I would recommend working on one, for example English, and calling it up.
(The code snippet you are looking for is at the ground of the files.)

Comment: How to set a message in Polish?

Comment: I dont have folder "assets". Where I can write text in polish?

Comment: So, I revised it again, I had used the wrong installation line for pubspec.yaml. I also explained it again in more detail. ; )